# Fwrite does not write file when spaces or <> are in the datastring

Tags: php, ajax, encode, fwrite

I have a contenteditable table in HTML that I'm writing to a file through ajax and PHP fwrite. It works, except whenever there is a space, < or > (`&nbsp;` or `&lt;` or `&gt;`) in one of the contenteditables, the writing does not happen, no error codes are shown. All the code is in one .php file.

```
var table = $('.table-editable')[0].outerHTML;
var data = 'data='+table+'?filename='+filename;
//var dataencoded = encodeURI(data);

$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType:"html",
    data: data ,
    success: function (response) {
       // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                         

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }


});
response.innerHTML='created';
}
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump($_SERVER);
$post_data = $_POST['data'];

$datas = explode("?filename=", $post_data);

if (!empty($datas[0])) {
$filename = $datas[1].'.php';
$towrite = htmlspecialchars_decode($datas[0]);
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $towrite);
fclose($handle);
echo $filename;
}
?>
```

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars` instead of `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: for `&nbsp;`, what's the problem ? You can use `html_entity_decode` if you want it converted into a space character

Comment: I just tried `htmlspecialchars` and `html_entity_decode` as replacements for `htmlspecialchars_decode`, but the issue still persists.